# Disable TCP-fallback for QUIC

Tags: google-chrome, tcp, fallback, quic

I wanted to know whether it is possible to disable tcp fallback in case of QUIC at browser level(chrome browser). If yes then how.

Comment: There is no TCP fallback for QUIC. If it is TCP, then it is not QUIC anymore. Do you mean if you can enforce the use of HTTP/3 (based on QUIC) and disable use of HTTP/2 and HTTP/1 inside the browser? I doubt so, since most sites don't support HTTP/3 and thus would not be accessible anymore.

Comment: Yes when you enforce the use of HTTP/3 and disable HTTP/2 from the chrome flags setting. And there is TCP fallback whenever QUIC could not establish a connection, it fallback to tcp so my question is for the applications that support QUIC, is it possible to stop this tcp fallback.

Comment: I don't understand the use case. If HTTP/3 works it will not fall back. If HTTP/3 does not work it need to fall back to something which works. If you want only HTTP/3 working then only offer HTTP/3 on the server side, in which case a fallback will not work.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct and I agree that if I just want HTTP/3 to work then I have to fix it at server side to prevent this fallback but I was just wondering that is it possible to do it at the client side also for the cases when you don't have access to the server.

Comment: Again, I don't understand the use case of why do you want to disable the fallback in the first place. Disabling it means that the communication will simply not work if HTTP/3 cannot be established (for example because of a UDP blocking firewall), which is in the usual use cases not the expected behavior.

Comment: Okay I got your point, even if its possible to do (let's suppose) it doesn't make sense as it will simply stop the communication and rather than solving one problem it will create new problem out of it. Thanks Steffen